# MySQL: Update a value if an another value for this line is equals to a value from a 'list' of 10 000 values

Tags: mysql, sql

I must update an (emails) fields in Mysql (compagnie) table. I search a solution to compare each lines with a list (CSV file) that contains only unsubscribed emails. If the emails is unsubscribed, then I must update (newsletter) fields for this line and set to NO. Probably, that I should import my CSV file with 10,000 inscribed emails in a column of my table or one another table to make a comparison? Also, I think create an index and lock the table.

E.g. to make an update but I must enter the email manually:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON compagnie (emails); 
LOCK TABLES compagnie WRITE;
UPDATE compagnie SET newsletter='NO' WHERE email='user@mail.com';
UNLOCK TABLES compagnie WRITE;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need, just implode the list of email and do comparison in single query like

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON compagnie (emails); 
LOCK TABLES compagnie WRITE;
UPDATE compagnie SET newsletter='NO' WHERE email IN( ... );
UNLOCK TABLES compagnie WRITE;
```

`...` will be replaced by all emails you have in the CSV

such as `IN('email1','email2','email3',...)`

Comment: you sure do like to push the limits on string length! I know max_allowed_packet tops out at 1Gb, but still...

Comment: @dnagirl - I believe this is just a match and update task 10,000*100 bytes=100Mb, still alright. And if you save this long query into a file, and execute using `mysql < LONG_SQL_FILE` is not hurting at all.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to have two columns, unsubscribe and subscribe. Using join to update the subscribe table.

```
UPDATE subscribe
SET newsletter = "No"
FROM
  subscribe
  Join unsubscribe ON (subscribe.email = unsubscribe.email);
```